# How to format "dd/mm/yyyy" of string type to "yyyy-mm-dd" enclosed in single quotes in python?

Tags: python, pandas

Problem Statement: assign the date (where there is maximum pressure difference) in string format as 'yyyy-mm-dd'. Make sure you enclose it with single quote.

test.py file is provided with the question for checking my notebook. Its read only and I am not allowed to edit it.

test.py

```
import re
from hashlib import md5
import nbformat
import pickle

def read_ipynb_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as file:
        out = str(nbformat.read(file_path, as_version=4))
    return out

path = 'question/EDA_question.ipynb'

out = read_ipynb_file(path)


max_p_range_day =  re.findall(r'max_p_range_day\s*=\s*\'\d*[-,]?\d*[-,]?\d*\'', out)[0].replace(' ', '').replace(' ', '').replace("'", "")
```

Error:

```
___________________________ ERROR collecting test.py ___________________________

test.py:23: in <module>

    max_p_range_day =  re.findall(r'max_p_range_day\s*=\s*\'\d*[-,]?\d*[-,]?\d*\'', out)[0].replace(' ', '').replace("'", "")

E   IndexError: list index out of range
```

In dataset "Day" column has dates which are type strings like this: "23/03/2018".

My code:

```
....
df5=pd.to_datetime(df5['Day']).dt.date  # date which has maximum pressure diff   

from datetime import datetime
max_p_range_day = datetime.strftime(df5.values[0],"'%Y-%m-%d'")
```

This is printing the date in single quotes but shows error when test.py evaluates it.

For checking myself, I tried this:

1. wrote max_p_range_day in file -

Content of file:

```
max_p_range_day = '2018-03-23'
```

2. Then did this:

   x=open("handson_date.txt",'r')

   out=x.read()

   res=re.findall(r'max_p_range_day\s*=\s*\'\d*[-,]?\d*[-,]?\d*'', out)[0].replace(' ', '').replace("'", "")

There was no error. res showed 'max_p_range_day=2018-03-23'.

But when my code is tested using test.py the error is thrown.

Kindly suggest how to address this concern.

Comment: In test.py, what is the output of "out"? Have you printed it?

Comment: probably the `re.findall` doesnot return anything. if you index an empty list for example :  `l=[]` and `l[0]` you get the same error

Answer (score 1):

This question requires each variable to be printed out in the cell.
For example-
After getting the value of `max_p_range_day`, print it out like
`print("max_p_range_day = '2018-03-23'")`
and then run the cell to get the output printed. After doing it for each variable then only run the test.py .

This question does not check the value in the variable but rather what is printed in each cell. This is what that regular expression is for.

```
res=re.findall(r'max_p_range_day\s*=\s*\'\d*[-,]?\d*[-,]?\d*'', out)[0].replace(' ', '').replace("'", "")
```

Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code with below

```
re.findall(r"max_p_range_day\s*=\s*'\d*[-]\d*[-]\d*'",out)[0].replace(' ', '').replace("'", "")
```

This will work with you